# Cross Platform compilation : property with 'retain (or strong)' attribute must be of object type

Tags: xcode, react-native, clang, node-gyp, djinni

I need help to decypher a compilation error with a specific Objective-C++ file.
It is included in an Xcode Project. In this context it compiles without errors.

I have seen many other questions about this error but none of them helped me so far.

Here is the command line produced by XCode 9.3, where I have removed options not tied to my problem:

```
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x objective-c++ -arch x86_64 
-fmessage-length=0 -fdiagnostics-show-note-include-stack -fmacro-backtrace-limit=0 
-std=gnu++11 -stdlib=libc++ -fobjc-arc -DDEBUG=1 -DOBJC_OLD_DISPATCH_PROTOTYPES=0 
-isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator11.3.sdk 
-fasm-blocks -fstrict-aliasing -mios-simulator-version-min=8.0 -g -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -fobjc-abi-version=2 -fobjc-legacy-dispatch -MMD -MT dependencies
```

I'm using [node-gyp](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp) / [djinni](https://github.com/dropbox/djinni) to build the same code in a cross platform way.
Here is the objective c gyp target:

```
  {
      "target_name": "djinni_objc",
      "type": "static_library",
      "xcode_settings": {
        "CLANG_ENABLE_OBJC_ARC": "YES",
      },
      "sources": [
        "<!@(python glob.py objc  '*.cpp' '*.mm' '*.m' '*.h')",
        "proxy_cache_impl.hpp",
        "proxy_cache_interface.hpp",
      ],
      "include_dirs": [
        "objc",
      ],
      "direct_dependent_settings": {
        "include_dirs": [
          "objc",
        ],
      },
    },
```

This target produces this clang command line:

```
c++ '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=djinni_objc' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-D_DARWIN_USE_64_BIT_INODE=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' 
'-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' -Os -gdwarf-2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -arch x86_64-Wall -Wendif-labels -std=gnu++0x 
-stdlib=libc++ -fno-threadsafe-statics -fno-strict-aliasing -fobjc-arc -fno-strict-aliasing -fobjc-arc -fobjc-arc -MMD
```

Once again I have removed compilation options that are not tied to the problem.

The compilation error is:

error: property with 'retain (or strong)' attribute must be of object type

> @property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) dispatch_queue_t methodQueue;

So I'm looking for the [entry(ies)](https://pewpewthespells.com/blog/buildsettings.html) to be placed in the .gyp file section "xcode_settings" to have this error go away.

Any help appreciated.

**EDIT**: It is an Objective-C++ file.

**EDIT 2**: I've managed to add `-x objective-c++` to the command line but the error is still there :(

**EDIT 3**: The solution to this problem is to edit the node-gyp common.gypi file to comment/remove the following xcode.settings:

> ```
>      'MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET': '10.7',       # -mmacosx-version-min=10.7
> ```

if you've installed it globally it is probably located in /users/*username*/.node-gyp/*node-version*/include/node

Replace username and node-version by the appropriate values.

I'd like this question to remain open to suggest a better option to negate this settings.

Comment: What's your filename?  It looks like the gyp-generated command line may be trying to compile the file as C++ (.cpp) not Objective-C++ (.mm), which I'd expect to cause a lot of issues for an @property.  The specific error suggests the definition of dispatch_queue_t isn't being properly expanded, possibly due to #ifdefs, which would certainly be messed up if the compiler is configured for the wrong language.

Comment: it is a .mm (Objective-C++). I'll look into it. thanks.